# how to configure dc.bubbleOverlay(): min and max radius, text in bobble

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

for the first time I'm making a Bubble Overlay Chart using dc.js. I followed the [api](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#bubble-overlay-chart) and the [example page](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/crime/index.html)

I set the radius scale like this

```
.r(d3.scale.sqrt().domain([0, 300000]))
```

but the output radius value are not mapped to any range and there is no max value and the min value is constrained to 10. How can I set the range con the radius scale?

By default the Bubble Overlay Chart output the name of the point in a text element. I don't want this. There is a way to disable the text element?

**[edit]**
About the label inside the bubble I have just found out there is the .renderLabel(boolean) that makes what I need. Without the label should not be the min radius of 10px.
I've still no solution for the radius range...

Thanks
Daniele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's one of the limitations of the bubble chart and bubble overlay chart. If you don't need the "overlay" part you could consider using the scatterplot of dc 2.0.

Or if you're able to change the source, I have heard from others that they had success simply going in and changing the minimum radius. :-/

Comment: yes, for now I've st the min radius to 1... and it is possible to "manage" the max radius playing with the max value of the domain. I have set it 3 times bigger than the max value of the dataset and now the radius of the bubble looks good. not so simple :-(